# Xcode 4 Quick Help Not Showing Much iOS Information

Tags: xcode, ios

Just installed Xcode 4 using the default installation and am programming an iOS application.

When I use the Quick Help feature however, the only thing that is usually displayed is the name of the selected symbol and what header file it is in. Is there any way to show more information, like what is shown in Quick Help samples in the Xcode 4 user guide, such as: Declaration, Abstract, Reference, etc. Or perhaps iOS does not have an extensive Quick Help?

Comment: Have you checked if you have downloaded the latest documentation sets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that was it. Even though I did a default installation, including documentation, the documentation sets were not installed.

So I went to Preferences: Documentation, and then installed the documentation sets manually and now everything works.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode, got to Preferences -> Documentation (Thanks user542428) and press "Check and Install Now"*  This will cause the iOs documentation to appear in the list, so that you can press "Get" to download it.

(I got thrown off by the '+' for a while, but it required knowing a URL.)

- "Check and Install Now" will download the existing docs, so your internet connection may be tied up for a while.